# Cannot define certain "needle" in search_slow and search_fast algorithms in python

Tags: python, algorithm, timeit

I'm trying to time the search_slow and search_fast algorithms in order to see if there is a significant difference between the two and running this code on different computers to see the time difference also. I have gotten them to work, however, the needle does not seem to be working.

It does not seem to matter if the certain word is in the text file or not, it should return false if the needle was not found in the test.txt file. A bit difficult to explain so I hope that the code below will explain a bit more on what I'm trying to do:

```
import timeit

haystack = open('test.txt', 'r+')
haystack = list(haystack.read().split())
needle = "Hello"

def search_fast(haystack, needle):
    for item in haystack:
        if item == needle:
            return_value = True        
        return True
    return False


def search_slow(haystack, needle):
    return_value = False
    for item in haystack:
        if item == needle:
            return_value = True
    return return_value



search_slow(haystack, needle)
print(timeit.timeit("search_slow(haystack, needle)", setup="from __main__ import search_slow, haystack, needle"))

search_fast(haystack, needle)
print(timeit.timeit("search_fast(haystack, needle)", setup="from __main__ import search_fast, haystack, needle"))
```

The contents of test.txt are:

```
This is a random text file to test !
```

The values that I am getting when I run the program are:

> 0.77570605278
>
> 0.187502861023

Comment: Please describe what is currently happening and then explain how this deviates from what you are expecting.

Comment: I think what is currently happening is that it goes through the test.txt file, and then takes the time of how long it took for it to go through the text file.

What I'm trying to achieve is adding a much larger text file and seeing how long it takes to find a certain element or symbol in the text file.

Currently the needle does nothing, and the program returns a certain time even if the element or symbol, AKA "needle" is not present in the text file.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in `search_fast` you have a bug.  Here is a fixed version.

```
def search_fast(haystack, needle):
    for item in haystack:
        if item == needle:
            return True
    return False
```

That said, you have two possible causes of confusion.  For the first try to print the haystack.  Did you expect it to have a list of words, or a list of full lines?

The second one is that you have no code that does anything interesting if you find the needle.  You just return it.  So how would you expect to know that it had been found?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, i fixed the the little bug. To answer your questions:

1) I printed haystack and it came up as open file 'test.txt' - I am not actually trying to print the contents, just trying to see how long it takes for the program to run using the 2 search algorithms - i added the list since i thought it would make a difference, but seems that it was pointless of me :/
2) My main goal is to see how fast the needle is located in the test.txt file and displaying the time it took to find it

Comment: Just another thought that came to mind: maybe i should just ditch the .txt file and make haystack into a list that ranges from 1 - 1000 and see how fast it takes to find a certain number, like 57 for example ? since my main goal is to test how fast it runs on different computers and seeing if there is a signifcant difference in processing power etc

Comment: @user3062391 What is the point of the benchmark?  If you perform it carefully you'll find that a needle fraction `x` of the way through a long list will be found in fraction `x` of the time.  On average that means that the fast version executes 2x as fast as the slow one.  Now you don't need to benchmark!